# NSJSONSerialization returning nil

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services, nsdata

```
{"User":{"id":"42","name":"martin"}}
```

Converting my NSData to NSString returns this JSON which seems completely valid, however the method:

```
[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data]
```

is saying this is not a valid JSON object.

Could anyone point out a mistake I have made or think of a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I bet there is a non-printable character in your string for example, making the data invalid.

Declare an `NSError* error` variable then call `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]` method to try to convert the JSON: obviously if your data is considered invalid, it will return `nil`, but at least you will have the description of what's wrong in the `NSError* error` variable after that.

```
NSData* data = ... // your data
NSError* error = nil; // Declare a variable to hold the error upon return
id obj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // Try to convert your data
NSLog(@"obj: %@ ; error: %@", error); // Log the decoded object, and the error if any
```

Comment: I put the error and it said null, somehow it suddenly worked…weird…anyhow it works now!

Comment: I had the same problem and i get: `(Unescaped control character around character 43579.) UserInfo=0x9b78e30 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 43579.}`. How do i fix it?

Comment: Fix your JSON original data. I bet the JSON you are trying to decode is not valid JSON data at the beginning and has an invalid character at offset 43579, as the error explains. Paste your JSON into http://jsonlint.org/ to check its it is invalid or malformed JSON for example. If it's not valid JSON, you obviously need to fix it at the source _(fix the content of the `file.json` if you are reading your `NSData` from such a file, or fix the string generated by your WebServer if it's a Web Service that returns this JSON to your app into this `NSData`, etc…)_

Comment: Works for me. I minimized this to just using "NSError* error = nil;" and the code got running. Go figure.